# Architecture regarding MVC controller vs. separate Web API, how many projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In the past, I've always thought about exposing methods that will be consumed on the client side in an separate Web API project. Currently, I'm diving deeper into ASP.NET Core MVC and now understand what controllers are for. (I come from an ASP.Net webforms background)

Given that I might program an app (e.g., with Xamarin) in the future where I would consume most of the same methods from the Core MVC project, it would make sense to separate most of the functionality into a separate api.xxx.com Web API project.

From my point of view, ASP.NET Core MVC controllers are very similar to Web API projects and I fail to see a big difference in terms of consuming them. Basically, I'm confused as to whether have two projects (Core MVC project and separate Web API project) or just a single one.

1. Should I use two projects or just one? What are the advantages and disadvantages? If I use two, based on which criteria do I decide where to add new code? Can I move almost any (what's the exception) code from the controllers in the Core MVC project into the Web API project? Is that a good approach or a bad one?
2. How should I handle the client side login? I know that I can get token-based authentication with OWIN for my Web API project but how should I combine the authentication from the ASP.NET Core MVC project with the Web API project?
3. Let's assume that I decide to just use one project for both. How much overhead is there if the Xamarin app would call the MVC project all the time instead of the Web API project?

Comment: You can have one web project having both MVC and Web API. While mvc controllers will be used by web app views the web API controllers can be used to expose apis to the clients. And they both can work together for authentication and authorization

Comment: Ah, so I guess the difference is not what the methods consume but rather what kind of content they return, e.g., a View or an IEnumerable. A quick idea: I could call the Web API project from controllers methods in the MVC project, hmm

Comment: Calling web API from mvc controller would introduce one more hop and moving part in the application you need to worry about. If you have a common place which will just return data then you can use it from both mvc and API controllers and use the data either to send to view as model or return as json to the API client

Comment: Here I assume that you have a web application which will be used by user from browser and there will be client application such as mobile apps which will use the web apis to save and retrieve data.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Could you please clarify on 'if you have a common place which will just return data'? Currently, I have a business logic project that is consumed by the web project directly. If I decide to have two separate project, I will definetly reference the business logic project from both.

Comment: The business logic layer you can use in web API controllers too. That's what I meant. You can have web API controllers and mvc controllers in the same project. You don't really need two separate web projects.

Comment: Some concepts are getting mixed. (I think it's the comments, not the OP.) Putting different controllers in different projects doesn't mean an extra hop. Putting them in different applications does. An application can reference controllers defined in multiple projects. There are no "hops" involved with using controllers referenced in another assembly. If you think it's reasonably likely that you will need to separate them then you might as well. That way you can ensure that the two sets of controllers don't become coupled to each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack in your question. First to your general inquiry:

> From my point of view, ASP.NET Core MVC controllers are very similar to Web API projects and I fail to see a big difference in terms of consuming them. Basically, I'm confused as to whether have two projects (Core MVC project and separate Web API project) or just a single one.

That's because there's functionally no difference. In ASP.NET Core, controllers are controllers are controllers. The designations of MVC/Web Api are merely about *style*. In the former, you'll return views, while in the latter, you're return something like JSON.

Now in truth, the styles have diverged a bit more in later versions of ASP.NET Core. API controllers now usually inherit from `ControllerBase` rather than `Controller` and have the `[ApiController]` attribute applied. However, even this is not a *real* difference. The attribute just adds some sugar that makes building APIs a bit easier: returning 400 automatically when `ModelState` is invalid, switching the default bind from `FromForm` to `FromBody`, etc. It's all stuff you *could* do with MVC just as well. Using `ControllerBase` just excludes stuff included in `Controller` that's unnecessary for APIs. There's no `View` method to return because you won't be returning views from an API, for example. Everything else functions the same.

Long and short, it's pretty much about *how* you implement the controller, not any specific choice of using MVC or Web Api.

Now, as to your specific questions:

> 1. Should I use two projects or just one? What are the advantages and disadvantages? If I use two, based on which criteria do I decide where to add new code? Can I move almost any (what's the exception) code from the controllers in the Core MVC project into the Web API project? Is that a good approach or a bad one?

Again, a lot here to unpack. Simply, there's no right answer, and frankly, you don't have to decide right now. You can start with just one project mixing and matching MVC and Web Api controllers. Then, if you find a specific need, you can always create a new project and move your Web Api controllers over there. It just depends on your requirements and the needs of your application(s), which unfortunately no one can speak to but you. My best advice always, though, is to start small. Get out of the weeds and just build something. You aren't carving in stone; anything can be refactored later.

> 2. How should I handle the client side login? I know that I can get token-based authentication with OWIN for my Web API project but how should I combine the authentication from the ASP.NET Core MVC project with the Web API project?

Once you start talking about authenticating multiple apps, you really need to start looking at a centralized identity solution. There's out of the box, low config solutions like Azure AD or Auth0, or you can roll your own with Identity Server. It basically boils down to what you're willing to pay and how involved you want to be.

> 3. Let's assume that I decide to just use one project for both. How much overhead is there if the Xamarin app would call the MVC project all the time instead of the Web API project?

I don't think you're looking at this the right way. Requests are requests and the question is merely one of scale. The difference between one app (one project) and multiple is simply whether all the requests go to one place or many. However, you can always both vertically (resources) and horizontally (more instances) scale even just one app. So, the performance isn't honestly a concern here. In either form, you're scaling, just in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the complexity that you aim for.
In my point of view the clear way the best. 
With **ASP.NET Core using Domain-Driven Design concepts and patterns**, it's a good way to go. 
Check [Clean Architecture](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture) from Steve Smith, and give it a try.

example how you can organise it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Crish already mentioned that Start small into single project and eventually you can move things. Later on you can decide to have multiple projects. That's a good start however it mixes the things - all of your UI (cshtml or angular or whatever UI you want to have), all your data contracts, API, Controllers and everything.

> **Why we have MVC and Web Api technologies out there?**

It's a big question and you have your answer in that question : **Separation of concerns**.
It's a key while designing the application architecture. The idea is to avoid co-locating different concerns within the design or code. For example: You have the MVC Controllers that returns the views, and you have the other API controller which returns only Data. If you mix these things together I think it's a violation of that rule. **While designing the architecture separation of concern is key component of Building layered applications**.

Separating all the logics across different layers will allow ANY functionality to be added/remove later and it even allows you to support other third party consumers. As long as all these abstractions are properly grouped then you will achieve the good architecture that will be the best from any perspectives.

My suggestion is to use the DDD Pattern with SoC principle. BUT, all these efforts make sense if you have Big application that you need to extend over the time. I would start documenting all the modules you might have. If I would follow the above Pattern and Principle, I would end up having individual api.xxxmodule project for all the modules - DDD Pattern. I would have MVC, Authentication/Authorization API Project as separate.

> If you follow those 2 principles, your application will end up having
>   separate module for everything - each module act as an Individual app!

Hope you can imagine the benefits of them from all the perspectives. It has a huge huge benefits in term of managing, extending, changing, scaling, development, etc. Because each pieces works as an individual app, you can focus on all modules one by one rather than thinking mixed.

Comment: See also hexagonal architecture. Layering is good, but devs tend to get side-tracked on layers that don't add much or any value. Simply, you want to segregate your domain from your technical architecture. The domain is all about your business; it doesn't care what is using it. The technical architecture is the adapter that allows you to operate on the domain (i.e. your API). Any more layers you're adding that that should be deeply questioned.